# T-SQL syntax for creating table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to make a table of `student marks list`.

In one column the data need to be sum of the `columns` in the same row

```
 ex roll_no  Maths1   maths2    physics    total
    12        48       50       60         158
```

How can I create a table for the above solution in SQL Server?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: please be clear, it is mysql, sqlserver.

Comment: what is your input

Comment: You'll get  **ALL** your answers when you study the [**official MS docs** about `CREATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly.

You can use `computed column definition` to achieve the same. please check below sql to test.

```
CREATE TABLE students_mark_list
(
     roll_no int,
     Maths1  int,
     maths2 int  , 
     physics int  ,  
     total  AS Maths1 + maths2 + physics
);

INSERT INTO students_mark_list (roll_no, Maths1 , maths2 , physics) VALUES(1, 10,20,30);
SELECT * FROM students_mark_list;
```

For more details You can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you this one is exact statement i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a column as total if not there is your table schema.

Then you can update that record with the sum of your columns like:

```
  update table set total = col1 + col2 + col3 where rollno = @rollno
```

Or

If you just need it for computation purpose:

```
 select rollno, col1, col2, col3 , (isnull(col1, 0) + isnull(col2, 0) + isnull(col3, 0) ) as Total from table
```

For more info you may find this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: There's no need to create an entire new column just to hold a total. Unless this will be a frequently queried column. Then SQL has the ability to run computed columns that will also make an UPDATE unneeded. And relying on an UPDATE will prevent the total column from being real-time.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
CREATE TABLE Marks
(
     COL1 int,
     Col2   int,
     COl3 int  , 
     Col4 int  ,  
     Sum AS Col2+Col3+Col4
)

INSERT INTO Marks SELECT 10,90,91,98

SELECT * FROM MARKS
```